# Restrict my certificate list on the basis of ExpirationDate in certutil -view -restrict cmd

Tags: cmd, certificate, pki, certutil

Is there a way to restrict my certificate list on the basis of ExpirationDate of a certificate in `certutil -view -restrict` command?

I have nearly 2 million certificates. It is very hard to find in the excel file as excel does not open it very well

```
@ECHO
certutil -view -restrict "NotAfter>=2/22/2020 12:00AM , NotBefore>=3/13/2020 12:00AM , disposition=20" -out "RequesterName,CommonName,CertificateTemplate,NotAfter" csv > C:\Report\march2020.csv
```

Comment: Would it possible to post the command that I can use to get the certificate expiring on 25 March 2020 using certutil command in cmd

Answer (score 0):

To filter on the expiry of a certificate, use `Certificate Expiration Date` instead of `NotAfter`.

To show when a certificate expires on a specific date, you need to filter the output so that it restricts it to everything between the start of that date (25 March 2020 00:00) and the start of the day after (before 26 March 2020).  A date without time, is the equivalent of `00:00` on that date.

You can do this with:

```
certutil -view -restrict "Certificate Expiration Date >= 25/03/2020,Certificate Expiration Date < 26/03/2020" -out "RequesterName,CommonName,CertificateTemplate,Certificate Expiration Date" csv > C:\Report\march2020.csv
```

Note: The example uses `dd/mm/yyyy` for the date, but you should enter the date on your system in the format your locale expects.

To get a list of options on which you can filter run `certutil -schema`.

Comment: When i run this command it is returning all the certificate, it is not filtering the certificate on the basis of the Certificate Expiration Date

Comment: Works for me! Have you double-checked for typos?  Did you adjust the date format for your locale (if required)? What version of Windows are you running?